# Is there a better way of redirecting a page to another JSP than location.href in js?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Is there a better way of redirecting a page to another JSP than location.href in js? because I am using actions and I have to go back to a page on button click but through some action page but it gets executed only one time.not every time I hit the button.
Please Help here !

I have tried giving the url of action page in location.href

MYPAGE :

```
<c:url value="/src/index.action" var="indexUrl"/>
<input type="button" value="<<" onclick="location.href='${indexUrl}'" >
```

in action XML:

```
<action name="index" class="#someclass">
    <result name="success">src/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

in index page :

```
<frameset id="AapFrameSet" rows="350,*" border="0">
<frame src="src/list.action" name="list" />
</frameset>
```

in action XML:

```
<action name="list" class="someclass" method="method_name">
<result name="success">/src/list.jsp</result> --this is the actual page which I want on back button
</action>
```

Expected Output: when I hit the back button in MYPAGE it should go back to the List page and it should be doing this whenever I hit the back button on MYPAGE

Actual Output: When I hit the back button in MYPAGE  once it is going back to  list page but when I hit the back button second time in MYPAGE  it is not going back to list page.

Comment: I don't see any reason to involve buttons or JS for this. Just use a link.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin I have tried the anchor tag as well but I am facing the same behavior but when I open that link in new tab it gets open in new tab but then again in the new tab when I click again the back link now it does not open